# How to change CSS class depending on the value of variable in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

I have a variable `{this.state.prediction}` in JavaScript (ReactJS). I want to change circle color depending on the value of `{this.state.prediction}`.

In particular, when `{this.state.prediction}` is equal to 0, then `div class="circle"`, else `div class="circleSelected"`.

How can I implement it?

```
<div>
   <div class="circle-content">
      <div class="circle"></div>
      <p>[0 - 5] ({this.state.prediction})</p>
   </div>
   <div class="circle-content">
      <div class="circle"></div>
      <p>(5 - 15]</p>
   </div>
   <div class="circle-content">
      <div class="circle"></div>
      <p>(15 - 30]</p>
   </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.circle-content {
    width:20%;
    text-align:center;
    float:left;
}

.circle {
    display:inline-block;
    width:20%;
    padding-bottom:20%;
    border-radius:60%;
        background: #000;
    border:1px solid #000;
}

.circleSelected {
    display:inline-block;
    width:20%;
    padding-bottom:20%;
    border-radius:60%;
        background: #000;
    border:1px solid #000;
}

.circle-content p {
    font-size:14px;
    color:#fff;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it with ternary operator like this

```
<div className={this.state.prediction === 0 ? "circle" : "circleSelected"}></div>
```

Comment: in react we use `className` not `class` (at least in the current version)

Comment: @ScalaBoy it may change in the future, [there is a shift towards `class`](https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/13525#issuecomment-417818906) but for now [its `className`](https://reactjs.org/docs/faq-styling.html#how-do-i-add-css-classes-to-components)

Comment: It does not compile

Comment: `<div className={this.state.prediction} === 0 ? "circle" : "circleSelected"></div>
      |                                                            ^`

Comment: I get `^` under `===`.

Comment: You are missing `}`. Check my answer.

Answer (score 2):

The library [`classnames`](https://github.com/JedWatson/classnames) might help.

It's gives some nice syntax for what you're trying to do:

```
import React from 'react';
import classNames from 'classnames';


class SomeClass extends React.Component {
  render() {
    <div className={classNames({
      'circle': this.state.prediction === 0,
      'circleSelected': this.state.prediction > 0,
    })}></div>
  }
}
```

check out the documentation here: https://github.com/JedWatson/classnames#usage-with-reactjs

Comment: you are missing a single quote which will prevent this from working

Answer (score 1):

First, you shouldn't be using `class` to assign classes to elements rendered by React. You can read about this in the official [Styling and CSS](https://reactjs.org/docs/faq-styling.html) documentation.

Using JSX syntax, you have full access to JavaScript operators and logic. You can conditionally assign `className` by either passing in a variable that you conditionally assign such as `<div className={circleClass}></div>` or just writing a ternary inline such as `<div className={this.state.prediction ? "circle" : "circleSelected"}></div>`.

This situation is pretty common and when you have multiple classes that you want to toggle it can get pretty complicated. There is a nice utility library to assist with this called [classnames](https://github.com/JedWatson/classnames) that you should check out if you see this happening frequently.

Comment: What do you mean by `<div className={this.state.prediction ? "circle" : "circleSelected"}></div>`? I want tp check if `this.state.prediction` is equal to 0 or 1 or any other numeric value. How can I check this equality?

Comment: Sorry, that wasn't very complete. You can do any JS logical condition there such as `this.state.prediction === 1 ? "circle" : "circleSelected"` or `this.state.prediction > 0 ?  "circle" : "circleSelected"`. In complicated cases, you can even call a function there such as `className={getCircleClass(this.state.prediction)}` where `getCircleClass` returns either "circle" or "circleSelected";

Answer (score 0):

For more complex classes list you can make an array, it might look like this:

```
const classesArray = ["defaultClassName"] //or empty if no default class is required
if(anyCondition) {
    classesArray.push("classToBeAdded")
} else if(anyOtherCondition) {
    classesArray.push("anotherClassToBeAdded")}
```

Then in JSX you can use:

```
<div className={classesArray.join(' ')}> 
    Your div text
</div>
```